# Override a template of a uiComponent

Tags: magento2.3, uicomponent

I have overridden the template of a few uiComponents before, but this time whatever I attempt it doesn't work. Hopefully somebody has an idea what's going on.

First off, I used the layoutProcessor to search for the component i'm trying to edit, and changed the `['config']['template']` of the component.

When I inspect the frontend with the knockout-js browser plugin I see that my new path is there and should be functioning. Magento still uses the default ui/form/field component though.

Things I checked: caches have been cleaned and static content has been deleted and generated.
The component has no template declaration in the js file.

Anybody have a clue what could be going on?

PS if I change the `elementTmpl` instead of the `template`, it works as expected.